# How to form dates from looping numbers?

Tags: r

I am **scraping** a page and part of the link is a variation of dates.

I need to do a looping to change the dates in the link, then I can scrape all the pages I need.

The link is: https://www.dr.dk/nyheder/allenyheder/politik/20032019 for example.

And I need to take all the links from 01012019 to 20032019.

```
    # Defining URL
    dr.url <- "https://www.dr.dk/nyheder/allenyheder/politik/"

# Looping dates
for (year 2019:2019){
  for (month 1:12){
    if(month %in% c(1,3,5,7,8,10,12)){
       length.POSIXlt(31)
    } else if (month==2){
      length.POSIXlt(28)
    } else {
      length.POSIXlt(30)
    }
    
    for (day in 1:) {
      if(str_length(month) == 1) month <- paste0(0,month)
      if(str_length(day) == 1) day <- paste0(0,day)
      
      final.date <- paste0(day,month,year)
      
      final.url <- paste0(dr.url, final.date)
    }
  }
}
```

This does not work.

Is there any better idea? Or something that at least works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve this by using the Date format.

```
Enddate = as.Date("20032019", format = '%d%m%Y')
Startdate = as.Date("01012019", format = '%d%m%Y')

Dates = seq(Startdate, Enddate, by = "days")

Dates = format(Dates, "%d%m%Y")

> Dates
 [1] "01012019" "02012019" "03012019" "04012019" "05012019" "06012019" "07012019" "08012019" "09012019" "10012019"
[11] "11012019" "12012019" "13012019" "14012019" "15012019" "16012019" "17012019" "18012019" "19012019" "20012019"
[21] "21012019" "22012019" "23012019" "24012019" "25012019" "26012019" "27012019" "28012019" "29012019" "30012019"
[31] "31012019" "01022019" "02022019" "03022019" "04022019" "05022019" "06022019" "07022019" "08022019" "09022019"
[41] "10022019" "11022019" "12022019" "13022019" "14022019" "15022019" "16022019" "17022019" "18022019" "19022019"
[51] "20022019" "21022019" "22022019" "23022019" "24022019" "25022019" "26022019" "27022019" "28022019" "01032019"
[61] "02032019" "03032019" "04032019" "05032019" "06032019" "07032019" "08032019" "09032019" "10032019" "11032019"
[71] "12032019" "13032019" "14032019" "15032019" "16032019" "17032019" "18032019" "19032019" "20032019"
```

Comment: I got another issue with the scrapped data. I need to remove parts of it. How could I do that? I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
 library(tidyverse)
    library(lubridate)
    dr.url <- "https://www.dr.dk/nyheder/allenyheder/politik/"

    dfrom <- '01012019'
    dto <- '20032019'
    Daten <- dmy(dfrom)
    while (Daten < dmy(dto)) {
      print(paste0(dr.url,as.character(as.Date(Daten), "%d%m%Y")))
      Daten <- Daten +1
    }
```